# $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded. >> error in CDF deployment

Tags: cdf-format

When I am executing this code in notebook, there is no error but when I am deploying it in CDF, this error is coming.

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded. >>

The code is

```
With[{y1 = {1, 2, 2, 1, 7}, y2 = {0, 3.27, 4.188, 7.331, 4.694}}, 
 Column[
   { Spacer[70], 
     Text[Style["iPhone and iPad quarterly sales- units, million", Bold, 18]], 
     Column[
       {Spacer[70], 
        Text[Style["Click on/off:", Bold, 14]], 
        q1 = True; q2 = True;
        Row[
          {Labeled[
             Button["     ", q1 = ! q1, Background -> Blue, Appearance->"Frameless"],
             "iPhone", {Right}
           ], 
           Spacer[19], 
           Labeled[
             Button["     ",q2 =!q2,Background -> Orange, Appearance -> "Frameless"], 
            "iPad", {Right}
           ]
          }
         ], 
         Column[
           {Dynamic@ BarChart[
                       Table[{If[q1, y1[[i]], 0], If[q2, y2[[i]], 0]},{i, 1, 5,  1}], 
                       BarSpacing -> 0.8, ChartStyle -> {Blue, Orange}, 
                       ImageSize -> {600, 280}, 
                       GridLines -> {None, Automatic}
                     ]
           }
         ]}]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have tried using

```
$RecursionLimit = Infinity
```

But it has not worked. Please help.

Comment: There was one missing comma in your code. I've corrected that. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Now buttons are not working in cdf. But there is no error coming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it to work in my browser by replacing the first line by

```
DynamicModule[{y1 = {1, 2, 2, 1, 7}, y2 = {0, 3.27, 4.188, 7.331, 4.694}, q1, q2}
```

It has probably to do with this statement in [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CreateAComputableDocumentFormatFile.html):

> All interactive content must be generated with the Manipulate command

(and `DynamicModule` with all necessary variables localized is a good `Manipulate`proxy).

Comment: Thanks.....it is working. But can you tell me why it was not working earlier when I was using "With"?

Comment: You can try the CDF [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3675222/test.html)

Comment: @Jennifer explanation below the line of code